# Word Sense Disambiguation WordNet

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm working on my university project and I'm implementing the LESK Algorithm.
So far so good. With the words that have a synsets in Wordnet it works fine.

**What i'd Like to do is to work with the semcor corpus** (That i've already downloaded)

Here is the code:

```
def overlap_context(synset, sentence):
  gloss = set(WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(synset.definition()))
  for example in synset.examples():
    gloss.union(example)
  gloss = gloss.difference(stopwords)
  if isinstance(sentence, str):
    sentence = set(sentence.split(" "))
  elif isinstance(sentence, list):
    sentence = set(sentence)
  elif isinstance(sentence, set):
    pass
  sentence = sentence.difference(stopwords)
  return len(gloss.intersection(sentence))

def lesk_algorithm(word, sentence):
  best_sense = None
  max_overlap = 0.0
  word = wn.morphy(word) if wn.morphy(word) is not None else word
  for sense in wn.synsets(word):
    overlap = overlap_context(sense, sentence)
    for height in sense.hyponyms():
        overlap = overlap + overlap_context(height, sentence)
    if overlap > max_overlap:
        max_overlap = overlap
        best_sense = sense
  return best_sense
```

I've written the code, and as long as i pass the word and the sentence manually it works..
Since I'm working with the SemCor corpus from nltk, how can I work with 50 sentences from that corpus?

Comment: If the corpus is a csv/txt file, you can load it as pandas dataframe and using for loop, iterate over each sentence and within loop, call the lesk_algorithm' function. This will perform the task for every sentence. If you want to further store it, write it in a file or a list.

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar no' I'm using the nltk.corpus statement